# Is integer vectorization accuracy / precision of integer division CPU-dependent?

Tags: c#, vectorization, precision, simd, auto-vectorization

I tried to vectorize the premultiplication of 64-bit colors of 16-bit integer ARGB channels.

I quickly realized that due to lack of accelerated integer division support I need to convert my values to `float` and use some SSE2/SSE4.1 intrinsics explicitly for the best performance. Still, I wanted to leave the non-specific generic version as a fallback solution (I know that it's currently slower than some vanilla operations but it would provide future compatibility for possible improvements).

However, the results are incorrect on my machine.

A very minimal repro:

```cs
// Test color with 50% alpha
(ushort A, ushort R, ushort G, ushort B) c = (0x8000, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF);

// Minimal version of the fallback logic if HW intrinsics cannot be used:
Vector128<uint> v = Vector128.Create(c.R, c.G, c.B, 0u);
v = v * c.A / Vector128.Create(0xFFFFu);
var cPre = (c.A, (ushort)v[0], (ushort)v[1], (ushort)v[2]);

// Original color:
Console.WriteLine(c); // prints (32768, 65535, 65535, 65535)

// Expected premultiplied color:   (32768, 32768, 32768, 32768)
Console.WriteLine(cPre); // prints (32768, 32769, 32769, 32769)
```

I tried to determine what instructions are emitted causing the inaccuracy but I was really surprised to see that in SharpLab the results are [correct](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK4wD4AEBMBGAWACgsAGAAizwDoAldBKMAU2oEkYFlYBnKAYx4BuYsQAUqHgAsA9sgTkAgnHKTZ88rRVq5CgOLbpu8gCEAlOX7kAvOTGkAHgA5SrlY4BiXj+4fef5J7eZiJExABqzPwIcng4TgA8qLAIAHzkAG425JHRsfHUAMLIzBAIzGL8dCpVBpbUJu6oIcRZtlkAVPWK5AD0OVExyHFORSVlFUFezaEZEMiWAAol2ZXUynY68mYZANqkALoqEkbbe3hHm6cIO7s4By1hJHgAnJWPVG/8y8yPQA). On the other hand, the issue is [reproducible](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4AMEZS) in .NET Fiddle.

Is it something that's expected on some platforms or should I report it in the runtime repo as a bug?

---

#### Update

Nevermind, this is clearly a bug. Using other values cause totally wrong results:

```cs
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;

(ushort A, ushort R, ushort G, ushort B) c = (32768, 65535, 32768, 16384);

Vector128<uint> v1 = Vector128.Create(c.R, c.G, c.B, 0u);
v1 = v1 * c.A / Vector128.Create(0xFFFFu);

// prints <32769, 49152, 57344, 0> instead of <32768, 16384, 8192, 0>
Console.WriteLine(v1);

// Also for the older Vector<T>
Span<uint> span = stackalloc uint[Vector<uint>.Count];
span[0] = c.R;
span[1] = c.G;
span[2] = c.B;
Vector<uint> v2 = new Vector<uint>(span) * c.A / new Vector<uint>(0xFFFF);

// prints <32769, 49152, 57344, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0> on my machine
Console.WriteLine(v2);
```

In the end I realized that the issue was at the multiplication: if I replace `* c.A` to the constant expression `* 32768`, then the result is correct. For some reason the `ushort` value is not correctly extracted/masked(?) out from the packed field. Even `Vector.Create` is affected:

```cs
(ushort A, ushort R, ushort G, ushort B) c = (32768, 65535, 32768, 16384);

Console.WriteLine(Vector128.Create((int)c.A)); // -32768
Console.WriteLine(Vector128.Create((int)32768)); // 32768
Console.WriteLine(Vector128.Create((int)c.A, (int)c.A, (int)c.A, (int)c.A)); // 32768
```

---

#### Update 2

In the end filed an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/83387) in the runtime repo

Comment: In the meantime I realized that SharpLab also produces the wrong result in Debug mode. Strange, because on my computer both Debug and Release builds are incorrect. So I start to believe this is a bug after all.

Comment: This can be done with integer multiply and shifts, although it's not super efficient since it needs the high half of a 32x32 => 64-bit multiply, and SSE2 / AVX only gives you that with `pmuludq` which gives you the full 64-bit results.  So only half the input elements per vector.  https://godbolt.org/z/7E9P9aWMh shows GCC and clang using a multiplicative inverse for dividing a vector of 4x `uint32_t` by `0xffffu`.  This is exact integer division, no FP involved at any point.

Comment: I don't see anything in the software fallback path which would cause this... I'd be tempted to either raise this in the dotnet/runtime repo, or ask in `#allow-unsafe-blocks` on [discord](https://discord.com/invite/ccyrDKv) (lots of JIT people hang out there, and they'll tell you if you need to open an issue)

Comment: If you were using FP, it would probably perform better to multiply by `1.0f/0xffff` (or however you write a `float` constant in C#), although that can't be represented exactly. But with about 23 bits of precision, might still give the correct 16-bit integer after rounding or truncating to 16-bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, bit shifting is faster with vanilla code than division but the results are not exactly the same. And the floating point version now works well, it's just about the issue I noticed.

Comment: Alright, this must be a bug, using some other values end up in total off results. I will update the post soon.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg: The compiler output I linked is for `vec / 0xffffu`.  The results *are* exact, using a multiplicative inverse like I said, same as compilers do for scalar `uint / constant`.  [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935)  Did you think I meant `v >> 16`?  Oh, you probably thought I meant doing the `*` part of you expression with an integer multiply; I was talking about using the high half of integer multiply as part of the division.